# How to give File permission for creating and deleting a folder in online webserver using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can anyone tell how to give or set file permission for creating and deleting a folder in webserver!

Creating a Folder

```
        mkdir("FolderName", 0755, true);
```

Deleting a folder

```
    $files = glob("FolderName" . '*', GLOB_MARK );
chmod("FolderName", 0777);
foreach( $files as $file ){
    if( substr( $file, -1 ) == '/' )
        delTree( $file );
    else
        unlink( $file );
}
rmdir( "FolderName" );
```

The problem is that i am able to create and delete the folder in local server but i am not able to do that in online server? So can anyone tell how to enable permission through code using php?

Comment: Is it a linux or a windows machine?

Comment: In that case, make sure who's the user running the script (nobody/www-data/apache or others) and look into [chown](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php)

Comment: @DamienPirsy how to use chown.. before the creation of folder nor after it

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, you would want your main directory that holds the directories you are creating to be the same username and password as your web server, in this case my guess is Apache. Usually it's something like www-data.www-data - so you can run:

chown www-data.www-data

chmod 664

If you are still having troubles, try creating your directories in /tmp - although this is not a permanent solution it'll let you know if your code is working.